# How to intercept a request when using SpringBoot WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to use the `WebClient` to call my restServices. Previously on `RestTemplate`, we had `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` defined and attached to the `RestTemplate` to intercept and modify the requests. With the `WebClient`, is there a way to do the same ?

Thanks,

-Sreeni

Answer (score 17):

When you are using the WebClient Builder you can pass in implementations of the `ExchangeFilterFunction` interface using the `filter()` method. This is the equivalent of the `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` for `RestTemplate`.

WebClient Builder Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.Builder.html#filter-org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction-

ExchangeFilterFunction Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html

For example:

```java
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
        .filter(logFilter())
        .build();


private ExchangeFilterFunction logFilter() {
    return (clientRequest, next) -> {
        logger.info("External Request to {}", clientRequest.url());
        return next.exchange(clientRequest);
    };
}
```

Comment: I understand that this may be the equivalent of ClientHttpRequestInterceptor in a certain sense, but it doesn't give you very much access. For example, you can't see the body of the request.

Answer (score 11):

In my case i need to get Some headers from incoming requests and put them into my requests. I find what i need [here](https://developpaper.com/implementation-of-requestcontextholder-in-spring-boot-webflux/).

First of all a filter is needed

```
/**
 * ReactiveRequestContextFilter
 *
 * @author L.cm
 */
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnWebApplication(type = ConditionalOnWebApplication.Type.REACTIVE)
public class ReactiveRequestContextFilter implements WebFilter {

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        return chain.filter(exchange)
        .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put(ReactiveRequestContextHolder.CONTEXT_KEY, request));
    }
}
```

And `ReactiveRequestContextHolder`

```
/**
 * ReactiveRequestContextHolder
 *
 * @author L.cm
 */
public class ReactiveRequestContextHolder {
    static final Class<ServerHttpRequest> CONTEXT_KEY = ServerHttpRequest.class;

    /**
     * Gets the {@code Mono<ServerHttpRequest>} from Reactor {@link Context}
     * @return the {@code Mono<ServerHttpRequest>}
     */
    public static Mono<ServerHttpRequest> getRequest() {
        return Mono.subscriberContext()
            .map(ctx -> ctx.get(CONTEXT_KEY));
    }

}
```

And finally like Michael McFadyen say you need to configure an `ExchangeFilterFunction`, in my case i need Auth and origin:

```
private ExchangeFilterFunction headerFilter() {
    return (request, next) -> ReactiveRequestContextHolder.getRequest()
            .flatMap(r -> {
                ClientRequest clientRequest = ClientRequest.from(request)
                        .headers(headers -> {
                            headers.set(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN, r.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.ORIGIN));
                            headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, r.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
                        })
                        .build();
                return next.exchange(clientRequest);
            });
}
```

EDIT: In newer versions of project reactor `Mono.subscriberContext()` does not exits. It must be changed with `Mono.deferContextual(Mono::just)`, And `.subscriberContext(ctx -> ...)` with `.contextWrite(ctx -> ...)`