# How to get the Request or the request body from org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, spring-webflux

I have a piece of code

```
    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    webClient.post()
                .header(AUTHORIZATION, BEARER + token)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(payment))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(Payment.class)
                .onErrorResume(exception -> Mono.error(new ApiException(exception)))
```

Is there any way to get the request or the request body as a string from this piece of code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to intercept a request when using SpringBoot WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726943/how-to-intercept-a-request-when-using-springboot-webclient)

Comment: @Strelok,Thanks for your effort, but is not what i am asking for. Please read this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726943/how-to-intercept-a-request-when-using-springboot-webclient#comment95560244_51728374

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If it's for logging purposes, the answer is different than if you want to actually do something else with the body.

Comment: @Frischling, I assume, the goal is to log _raw request body_ in a case of response error.