# How to consume spring web client response

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am using web client in a spring application

I am facing memory leak issues while doing the same

I am using below code to get the response body for non 2XX response from service:

```
return client.get()
                .uri(uriString)
                .headers(ServiceCommonUtil.getHttpHeaderConsumer(headersMap))
                .exchange()
                .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                    try {
                        clientResponse.body((clientHttpResponse, context) ->
                                clientHttpResponse.getBody());
                        logResponseStatus(clientResponse.statusCode(), serviceName);
                        return clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return null;
                    }

                })
```

and later on subscriber uses subscribe/ error block to process this response.

```
responseMono.subscribe(response -> {
    //process response string
},error->{
    //process error response
});
```

My question is, if i use dispose method on responseMono, it takes way long time for processing while without it i face memory leak issues.
Am i doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, actually you are not consumming response in case of Exception is thrown.

If you want to use `exchange()` your responsibillity is to consume response.
See: [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.html#exchange--)

Take a look on `toBodilessEntity()`/ `releaseBody()` in 'ClientResponse` api.

Comment: got it .. so you are saying instead of try / catch i just use
    clientResponse->clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)

will this release body or i still have to use releaseBody()

Comment: yeah, It will release body automatically

Answer (score 0):

Seems you've gotten a little complicated. Why a try/catch  block in the clientResponse lambda? If your `logResponseStatus` throws a checked exception then handle it there. I suggest starting simpler.

Ex 1:

```
Mono<String> stringMono = webClient.get().uri("test").header("head", "value").exchange().flatMap(clientResponse->clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class));
stringMono.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Ex 2:

```
Mono<String> stringMono = webClient.get().uri("test").header("head", "value").exchange().flatMap(clientResponse->clientResponse.body(BodyExtractors.toMono(String.class)));
stringMono.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

Ex 3:

```
Mono<String> stringMono = webClient.get().uri("test").header("head", "value").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
stringMono.subscribe(System.out::println);
```

For logging it is better to use `ExchangeFilterFunctions`. See [How to intercept a request when using SpringBoot WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726943/how-to-intercept-a-request-when-using-springboot-webclient)
.

Comment: yes try catch is actually unnecessary.. 

i want to but can't go with retrieve as i want body even in case of 4xx/ 5xx..
So just one basic q in Ex1/ Ex2, do i need to call releaseBody or dispose or they will internally take care of releasing the body and returning connection to the pool?

Comment: No, don't worry about the connection. That gets handled internally. You cannot return a null in a Mono/Flux or whatever, if you must have a try catch (not), then you will need to return `Mono.error(exception)`.