# Spring Boot & WebClient - how to add additional headers using @ConditionalOnProperty to a specific WebClient instance?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webclient, spring-properties

I have a service that is holding an WebClient instance:

```
@Service
@Getter
public class SomeApiWebClient {

    private final WebClient webClient;
    private final String someApiUrl;

    public SomeApiWebClient(@Value("${some.api.url}") String someApiUrl) {
        this.someApiUrl= someApiUrl;
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(someApiUrl)
                .defaultHeaders(getDefaultHttpHeaders())
                .build();
    }

    public Consumer<HttpHeaders> getDefaultHttpHeaders() {
        return headers -> {
            headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        };
    }

}
```

To call this API from UAT/PROD environments - this is just fine. But to call it from our local machines, we need to use `Client-ID` and `Secret` HTTP headers:

```
public Consumer<HttpHeaders> getDefaultHttpHeaders() {
    return headers -> {
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("Client-Id", "someId");
        headers.add("Secret", "someSecret");
    };
}
```

I have put the `someId` and `someSecret` values into `application-dev.properties`:

```
some.api.client-id=someId
some.api.token=someSecret
```

Now I would like to use `@Configuration` combined with `@ConditionalOnProperty({"some.api.client-id", "some.api.token"})` to intercept and add a filter to `MDSWebClient` that will add those headers when the `some.api.client-id` and `some.api.token` are present.

I have tried doing something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty({"some.api.client-id", "some.api.token"})
public class MDSWebClientInterceptor implements WebFilter {

    @Value("some.api.client-id")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("some.api.token")
    private String token;

    private static final String CLIENT_ID_HEADER = "Client-Id";
    private static final String CLIENT_TOKEN_HEADER = "Secret";

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return chain.filter(
                exchange.mutate().request(
                                exchange.getRequest().mutate()
                                        .header(CLIENT_ID_HEADER, clientId)
                                        .header(CLIENT_TOKEN_HEADER, token)
                                        .build())
                        .build());
    }

}
```

But this doesn't work at all, and I have a hunch that if it would work, it would affect ALL `WebClient` instances, not just the one in `SomeApiWebClient`.

Is something like this even possible?

Comment: Check if this contains any hint for solving that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726943/how-to-intercept-a-request-when-using-springboot-webclient. There is an example with ConditionalOnProperty but with different condition than the one you want.