Adapting RestTemplate Interceptor and HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory for a WebClient in SpringBoot 2.x
I have this custom Interceptor and trying to migrate to Spring Boot 2.7.18.
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestExecution;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestInterceptor;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;

@Slf4j
public class RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
    try {
      response.getHeaders().getContentType();
    } catch (InvalidMediaTypeException e) {
      if (e.getMediaType().contains("json")) {
        log.warn("Invalid MediaType detected:" + e.getMediaType() + ". Adapting to JSON.");
        response.getHeaders().put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE));
      } else if (e.getMediaType().contains("pdf")) {
        log.warn("Invalid MediaType detected:" + e.getMediaType() + ". Adaptando to PDF.");
        response.getHeaders().put(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE));
      }
    }
    return response;
  }
}

Previously, I changing the response! But for is not clear applying this according to ExchangeFilterFunction as https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728374/811293
In my RestTemplate:
      HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
      requestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);
      requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(30000);
  
      RestTemplate mtlsRestTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      mtlsRestTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
  
      List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = mtlsRestTemplate.getInterceptors();
      if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(interceptors)) {
        interceptors = new ArrayList<>();
      }
  
      interceptors.add(new RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor());
      mtlsRestTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
  
      return mtlsRestTemplate;

As you can see I'm including my custom RestTemplateHeaderModifierInterceptor class as interceptor in the restTemplate. And I'm using a HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory to change some values.
My Question is:

What would be the WebClient version?
How I must insert my interceptor in my WebClient (how change the response in a filter)?
About of requestFactory.setReadTimeout(30000) and requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(30000) how I must do it with a WebClient?

Thanks in advance
